# How to show my javascript counter result in 2 divs on the same page?

Tags: javascript, counter, clock

I have a javascript counter (named clock because it counts seconds) where the results are displayed in a div:

```
<div id="right">Time: <input id="clock" type="text" value="00:00" style="text-align: left; background:transparent; border-style: none; color:#ffbe5e; margin: 0px; font: 20px shanghai; width:60px;" readonly /></div>
```

This all works and it's displays counting the seconds. Now I want the same display results shown in a sec div at the same page, but how to do this? Simply copy and paste the code again doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,

ps I didn't post the javascript code cause it's a bit too big to copy/paste it in here. If you need it, let me know

Comment: When you copy-and-pasted the code to create a second instance of the div, did you: change the id of the div, change the id of the input, update your JavaScript to put the counter value into both the first input and the new one?

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I did copy all the clock values and changed the copied one to clock2. Seems I forgot to copy some code parts like `clock = document.getElementById('clock');` to change it to `clock2 = document.getElementById('clock2');` too. Funny, you brake your head trying to figure things out and it's right in front of you :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dgvid suggested above, please make sure to have separate ids for each counter you have.